# ¿De un Múltiple select Comenzar con unos ya seleccionados utilizando jquey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, web

Quiera que me ayudaran a solucionar lo siguiente.
Por ejemplo tengo la siguiente lista `multiple`

```
 <select multiple>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

Como hago para que cuando cargue el formulario ya aparezcan algunas seleccionadas utilizando `jquery`

Comment: Qué valores deseas seleccionar ? solo debes llamar al método `val`

Comment: @Dev.Joel digamos volvo y saab. Pero solo quiero saber como se hace por que realmente los va a quedar seccionados va a venir de una consulta a una base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes llamar al método [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) y asignarle un `array` que contendrá los valores a seleccionar

```js
var carros = [
    "saab",
    "volvo"
];

$("select").val(carros);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="opel">Opel</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta primero agregarle un ID al select para que sea fácil trabajar el jQuery. luego de esto puedes utilizar la funcion `$.each()`.

Mira un ejemplo.

**html:**

```
<select name='strings' id="strings" multiple style="width:100px;">
    <option value="Test">Test</option>
    <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
    <option value="Live">Live</option>
    <option value="Off">Off</option>
    <option value="On">On</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var values="Test,Prof,Off";
$.each(values.split(","), function(i,e){
    $("#strings option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

Intentalo y me cuentas :)